# Unable to move files into folders using batch files

Tags: batch-file, error-handling

i am trying to create folders using part of the file name (the first 10 digits unique digits) and then move the files to respective folders. I am able to create the folders but for some reason, unable to move the files into the folder. Any idea why? Here is my code:

```
@echo off
for /f %%a in ('dir /a-d /b') do (
  if not "%%~dpnxa"=="%~dpnx0" call :func "%%~a"
)
goto :EOF
:func
set file=%~1
set dir=%file:~0,10%
md "%dir%" 2>nul
move "%file%" "%dir%" 
goto :EOF
```

Comment: Turn echo on and run the batch file from the cmd prompt to debug the script.

Comment: Works fine for me. What message are you getting?

Comment: It only works when the file name only contain the 10digit number. However, my files contain other info eg(1234567890 CVI) and does not get filed. How can i modify my code such that the files will be filed base on the first 10 digits?

Comment: You need to provide an option string like `for /F "delims= eol=|"`, because otherwise your file names are split at the first white-space. Furthermore let me suggest to use the quoted syntax `set "file=%~1"` to protect from special characters.

Answer (score 0):

It works, but not if your filenames have spaces in them, it will still create most or entire folder, depending on where the spaces are, but not move the file..

So to rectify this try adding `"delims="` to the for loop to skip default delimiters by default being whitespace.

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /a-d /b') do (
  if not "%%~dpnxa"=="%~dpnx0" call :func "%%~a"
)
goto :EOF
:func
set file=%~1
set "dir=%file:~0,10%"
md %dir% 2>nul
move "%file%" "%dir%"
```

Answer (score 0):

Although it seems odd, you can use `RoboCopy` to 'move' files too. The following example uses the `Where` command to select only files which contain at least 10 characters, *(this means that you can keep your script name to less than 10 characters and you won't need to filter it)*:

```bat
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
For /F "Delims=" %%A In ('Where .:??????????*.*') Do (Set "FN=%%~nA"
    RoboCopy . "!FN:~,10!" "%%~nxA" /Mov>Nul)
```

*Please bear in mind that this doesn't prevent directories being created which end with spaces, i.e the 10th character of the filename is a <kbd>space</kbd>, which could cause you problems later!*